# "The system is going down for power off NOW!" - Windows Azure machine shut down itself, how to check for the cause of it?

Tags: linux, centos, azure

"The system is going down for power off NOW!" This is what I see from putty when SSH to my Centos VM on Windows Azure. Is there any log files that I can check to find out the cause of such failure? (just to make sure it is something like overheating and not receiving command from unknown place)

Comment: I'd very strongly doubt an Azure instance would overheat. This is almost certainly someone rebooting the instance, either via something like `reboot now` or Azure's control panel/API.

Comment: Hmm I surely doesn't issue such command, and supposedly no other have access to it. Is there a way to look into the details like log files?

Comment: Sure, take a look at `/var/log/auth.log` and the other logs in `/var/log`. See who logged in around then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Azure troubleshooting docs / FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg277962.aspx):

> **My roles instances restarted without me doing anything.**
>
> Service healing occurs automatically when the Windows Azure detects problematic nodes and moves role instances to new nodes. When this occurs, you might see your role instances restarting automatically.
>
> To find out if service healing occurred:
>
> In the Management Portal, click the deployment of your hosted service.
>
> In the Properties pane of the Management Portal, review the information and determine if service healing occurred during the time you observed the roles restarting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately for me there is no information about service healing in the said Properties pane. I wonder if there is more specific place to look into.

Comment: @StCee how often does this happen to your instance? Is it a frequent occurrence or rather like a once-in-a-hundred-years event?

Comment: It is a rare event. Only happen once for a few months (at least as I am aware of).

Answer (score 0):

As Virtual Machines are in *Preview* and not a production feature yet, there's really no SLA or information about when VMs are taken down due to maintenance reasons, such as Host OS updates.

As for timing: Yesterday there was some service interruption, as reported on the service dashboard (here's the [RSS feed](http://www.windowsazurestatus.com/windowsazure/support/status/RSSFeed.aspx?RSSFeedCode=WACEU)). I suspect this could be related to your VMs being rebooted.

Please see my [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15286175/272109) from yesterday as well regarding this.